# Why are the configuration styles inconsistent in gradle?

Tags: gradle

I am new to gradle and a few things of gradle confuses me. Some things appear like inconsistent coding / configuration style.

For example, when we configure the repository to be jcenter or mavencentral we call a function / method e.g. jcenter.

```
repositories {  
   jcenter()  
}
```

However, in the same file, when we try to configure a dependency we do not call functions / methods anymore.

```
dependencies {
   classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.1'
}
```

And then there are clearly variables getting values

```
productFlavors {
    prod {
        versionName = "1.0-paid"
    }
    mock {
        versionName = "1.0-free"
    }
}
```

I am sure there is a reason behind this perceived inconcistency but could not find anything when I read through the documentation. Could anybody explain the reason?

Answer (score 3):

Actually these examples are not so different.

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.1'
```

is a function call as well. Groovy (the language in which gradle build scripts are written) allows you to leave out the parenthesis around the arguments in many cases.

Comment: Thanks. That helps.

Answer (score 2):

This is the flexibility (I prefer this to inconsistency) that is delivered by Groovy the language that Gradle is using. 
In Groovy you can call a function/method with or without the parenthesis if its name is followed by matching arguments but if there are no arguments you must add parenthesis to make it a call to a function and make it distinct from the closure it represents. 
Here is an example using groovysh

```
groovy:000> def a(){println "a"}
===> true
groovy:000> a
===> org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.MethodClosure@95e33cc
groovy:000> a()
a
===> null
groovy:000> def b(arg){println arg}
===> true
groovy:000> b
===> org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.MethodClosure@d771cc9
groovy:000> b "argument"
argument
===> null
groovy:000> b("argument")
argument
===> null
groovy:000>
```

Comment: Very helpful. Now that I know that method calls can look different (with / without parenthese) in Groovy I guess I can see similarity in what looked different earlier to me. However, there still are some variable getting values set instead of method calls with parameters. Any comment on that?

Comment: Not sure what you mean without a solid example. Assigning a variable is clearly distinguished by using '=' - assign operator. When there is no '=' there must be a method call. 
However there is one twist to it. When '=' is used with fields groovy will call a setter if one exists. Please see this as example https://gist.github.com/anonymous/a1077e23489a9ea51813f87ad256dad6